# Why is rpart not splitting this data even when there is gain in gini?

Tags: r, decision-trees

```
df <- tibble(x1=factor(c("S1", "S1", "S2", "S2")), y=factor(c(1, 1, 0, 1)))
md <- rpart(formula=y~., data=df, method="class", control=rpart.control(minsplit=2, cp=0))
nrow(md$frame) #outputs 1
```

Consider the split

left child node:

```
"S1", 1

"S1", 1
```

Right child node:

```
"S2", 0

"S2", 1
```

Here the gain in gini would be ${1 \over 8} = 0.125$

Why is rpart not doing this split?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `rpart` is actually using accuracy rather than gini in the cost complexity pruning, see e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/223211/232706

Since your split doesn't improve the misclassification rate, `rpart` doesn't make it even with `cp=0`.  Setting `cp=-1`, the split is performed.